# How to submit the values of form before update and after update

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a form that retrieves data from a database and displays it in respective fields. The user then has the ability to make changes to the form and update those values. I'm able to correctly display the data from the database(SELECT) by clicking a submit button and update it as well(UPDATE) by clicking another submit button. What I want to do is store all the data before update in a separate table, sort of as an audit log that will tell me what the previous fields were and what the new update is like. I want to have both the Update and Insert query on the same submit button as well. How do I go about inserting the 'former' values in my table.

Here's my working update statement:-

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // Updating the dealer info using sfid

$sql = "UPDATE tbl_dealer_info ";
$sql .= "SET phone = '".$phone."', email = '".$email."', SFID = '".$sfid."', account_name = '".$account_name."', parent_account = '".$parent_account."', awi_code = '".$awi_code."', sales_portal_id = '".$sales_portal_id."', iae = '".$iae."', rsm_val = '".$rsm_val."', door_type_val = '".$door_type_val."', payment_method_val = '".$payment_method_val."', region_val = '".$region_val."', street_address = '".$street_address."', city = '".$city."', state = '".$state."', zip = '".$zip."', area = '".$area."', market = '".$market."', boost_app = '".$boost_app."', virgin_app = '".$virgin_app."', virgin_mob_app = '".$virgin_mob_app."', start_date = '".$start_date."', bank_name = '".$bank_name."', bank_acc_number = '".$bank_acc_number."', routing_number = '".$routing_number."' WHERE SFID = '".$sfid."' ";
$sql .= "LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: if you want to store it in another table, you'd need to run a separate query with an INSERT

Comment: am starting to wonder what the question is really about here and what code you need/have already.

Comment: Ok maybe I didn't explain myself properly. I select a user, then click submit and all the data for that user gets populated. I make relevant changes and then hit another submit button which runs the above update query. But before that update query, I want an insert query on the same button that will insert data into another table(WHICH ISN'T UPDATED).

Comment: It's worth pointing out that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.  You should be using prepared statements with query parameters.  This is not only for security but also for stability and control over the code you're executing.

Comment: You could have a `datetime` field on the table and just do an `insert` everytime. Then select the newest `tbl_dealer_info` when you need to data. Also the `SFID = '".$sfid."'` update is not needed.

Comment: @SukritJaie: Right, we get what you're trying to do.  What we don't get is what's stopping you from doing it.  You can execute an `INSERT` to copy the current state of the data to a new record.  You could even define a trigger to do this automatically so your PHP code doesn't have to.

Comment: that or run a multi-query; seems to be the/a solution for this.

Comment: For example, if I have a form with 2 fields : age and email. I select the name and it will display the age(20) and email(abc@hello.com). Then I will make changes to any of the fields (age changed to 24). Now when I hit a separate submit button, the updated age and email would go in one table(from where it is retrieved) and the original data would go to another table (age-20 and email-abc@hello.com)

Answer (score -2):

One easy way to do this is using hidden values example

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="phoneNumberNew">
<input type="hidden" name="phoneNumberOld">
</form>
```

With this what you can do is submit the form to wherever your table is held and populate the table where the textbox is the new data and the hidden one will be your old data. From there you can submit it onward using more hidden values or whatever means you see fit. This is just one option for you based upon technology everyone has available! :)

Comment: It's worth noting that this would allow the user to modify the "old" contents being logged.  Which wouldn't be ideal for an audit trail.

Comment: @David I'm not sure what you mean by modification of old contents. Cuz according to this answer, the old content is hidden and that would go into the log table, so how can the user modify it?

Comment: @SukritJaie: Open your browser's development tools (likely by pressing F12) and prepare to have your mind blown.  *Always* assume that *anything* sent from the browser to the server can be modified by the user.  Because, well, it can.

Answer (score -2):

When the user submits, the form data will be sent to the action="" page you defined.

In that page, run the select query again, which will give you the current values.
Then run the update query.

In your log you can then output the current values (from the select you did before), and the new values (from the update fields you got from the form).

--- Added this after the OP`s comment:

Let`s say you have a page like profile.php to update a user.
User A goes to profile.php?username=A
User B goes to profile.php?username=B
you can then build your select and update queries and specify which user you want to update.

Another method, which is better and more secure is to setup a session cookie.  You then read that cookie to know which session, and hence which user is using the page.

Obviously you want something to ensure the person modifying users is allowed to do so, but that is outside your question (users - roles - security management).

There will then be no chance of mixing up users.

Comment: Well yeah I didn't really specify a url for action, so it submits to the same page. Plus for the log, I only want the records for which an update was made. If I select user A by mistake and then pick user C and update C, i want the Insert of the old records and update of new records for C only and not A

Comment: If client A accesses page.php, and client B accesses page.php, you need something to differentiate the client.  Either via a session ID or something in the $_GET or $_POST that got him there.  Then in your log, put something like USER: old=blabla, new=tatatiti